# How to keep scroller in view inside of Fixed position div with top pixels pushing it down?

Tags: css, css-position, fixed

http://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/6rd2hhpq/8/

I'm working with a fixed position div and making elements scrollable from inside it. [Similar to this problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894400/fixed-position-div-scrollable).

I was able to get the scrollbars to show up, my problem is that I have a fixed header, and my fixed sidebar has to be pushed down in my view.

This allows the user to keep scrolling past the browser window so you lose sight of the scroller.

Is there anyway to keep the scrollbar in view with [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/6rd2hhpq/8/)?
So that when the scroller hits and stops at the bottom of the view, you also see the last item.

```
.red-box {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    color: white;
    background: red;
}

.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 60px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 180px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: @Shikkediel do you want to post the answer? That worked :) ...

Comment: Sure, I'll will promote the comment then! Glad that did the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the issue correctly - you want the fixed element to fill the screen apart from the header height... then you could try :

```
.not-stuck {
    height: calc(100% - 60px);
}
```

Looking at the other solutions on the page that was linked to, my personal second choice would be to use JavaScript (but the question doesn't have that tag of course).

Answer (score 0):

I changed the height to 90% and it seemed to work:

```
.not-stuck {
    position: fixed;
    top: 60px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    margin-left: 200px;
    width: 180px;
    height: 90%;
}
```

Comment: Thx, I see... it doesn't work all the time however, for example if I resize the browser window a little smaller and refresh

Comment: I guess it's a little hack, but height: 75% definitely seems to do the trick. Of course, I'm not sure if that fits with your purposes.

Comment: A percentage height may work for many screens, but beware; sometimes on very tall screens the scroll bar may stop slightly above the bottom of the region. I ran into the fixed value % problem when testing on portrait monitors... as I resized the window the "down" button in the scrollbar would disappear on small window sizes and have a blank margin on huge windows. The calc option works MUCH better.