# Fixed elements are out of browser's screen

Tags: html, css

I have two `position: fixed;` divs. Everything works fine until I zoom up the page. Normally when you zoom up page two sliders appear that allow you to see the rest of the page that is out of your screen. However, for some reason if those two divs that have fixed position  are out of screen the browser doesn't allow to scroll to them.

This doesn't happen if the divs don't have fixed position.
Is there ANY solution besides changing position to relative?

Comment: Throw this goodness into a fiddle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fixed position div scrollable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894400/fixed-position-div-scrollable)

Comment: That is because the fixed divs are outside the flow of the doc, and I'm assuming that you're using fixed values to position them as well. Since you don't provide any code, it's impossible to help.

Comment: Here's simple example of what I mean

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f29150k9/ posted twice by mistake

Comment: Yep, works perfectly now. Thanks.

Comment: OK, I posted that as an answer. And an explanation why there are no scrollbars if the block is fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed positioning means that the element is on a fixed position on the screen, no matter if you scroll or not.
In other words, the scrollbars (if any) won't have an effect on the fixed element.
So even if a browser *would* put scrollbars on the window if the fixed element came out larger, using those scrollbars would not scroll the fixed element into view!
So, no scrollbars. They would be useless.

One solution is to use `position: absolute` instead of `position: fixed`. Absolutely positioned elements do scroll with the page, so the scrollbars do work.

```html
<div style="position: absolute; margin-left: 50px; margin-top: 50px; width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: blue;">


</div>
```